# Inheritate Class from Float and append it to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, inheritance

If I have a custom class `CustomFloat` that inherits from `float` and I want to append instances of that class to a pandas DataFrame without losing the original datatype, how do I achieve this?

Suppose I got the following class:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Define the CustomFloat class
class CustomFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, value: float, unit: str = "", description: str = None):
        obj = float.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._unit = unit
        obj._description = description
        obj._u = obj.calc_u()
        return obj

    def calc_u(self):
        return 1 + 2
```

I tried adding it, however if I access the entries, the dataframe simply converts it to `float`.
This behavior is somehow expected, since it is actually a float, however I do not want the conversion to happen.

```py
# Create a DataFrame with a column of CustomFloat instances
f1 = CustomFloat(1.23)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': pd.Series([
    f1,
    CustomFloat(4.56),
    CustomFloat(7.89)
])})

print(f"f1: {f1} -- type {type(f1)}")
# However in pandas, my Datatype is not preserved
print(f"Column1[0]: {df['Column1'][0]} -- {type(df['Column1'][0])}")
```

I get the output

```
f1: 1.23 -- type <class '__main__.CustomFloat'>
Column1[0]: 1.23 -- <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Also my function `calc_u()` is not preset anymore. I tried it with panda's `astype()`, but it throws

```
TypeError: dtype '<class '__main__.CustomFloat'>' not understood
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Probably, check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extension-types